# Is it possible to block navigator "Edit and Resend" POST Request on the server?

Tags: php, ajax, http

I think i have a security problem in my application and i want to know what is the best practice to avoid that.

This is a part of my code :

```
try 
    {           
        $key = $_SERVER['HTTP_KEYID'];

        if ($key == KEY_SECURITY)
        {               
                $oUserBE->idUser = $this->post('idUser');
                $oUserBE->email = $this->post('email');

                $list = $this->UserDAO->getUsers($oUserBE, $return, $message);

                if ($return == 0)
                {
                    $oMessageBE->code = $return;
                    $oMessageBE->origen = "getUsers";
                    $oMessageBE->description = $message;
                    $oMessageBE->type = "OK";                   

                    $oResponseBE->message = $oMessageBE;
                    $oResponseBE->listUser = $list;
                }
                else
                {
                    $oMessageBE->code = $return;
                    $oMessageBE->origen = "getUsers";
                    $oMessageBE->description = $message;
                    $oMessageBE->type = "ERROR";

                    $oResponseBE->message = $oMessageBE;                    
                }
            }
            else
            {               
                $oMessageBE->code = 1;
                $oMessageBE->description = 'Incorrect security key';
                $oMessageBE->origen = "getUsers";
                $oMessageBE->type = "ERROR";

                $oResponseBE->message = $oMessageBE;                            
            }
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {           
        $oMessageBE->code = 1;
        $oMessageBE->description = $e->getMessage();
        $oMessageBE->origen = "getUsers";
        $oMessageBE->type = "ERROR";

        $oResponseBE->message = $oMessageBE;            
    }
```

The security key is in the header.

My problem is that in Firefox dev tools, when i'm logged in with one user then i can edit and resend the post request and it can return another user if i change only the user id or all users in my database if i send the request with no param. I want to block this possibility on my server.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ftA.jpg

Comment: Prior to processing any requests, you need to make sure that user that's submitting requests is authorized to make them. Keep user identifier in session variable, while all permissions in some other database. While it is possible to keep session state, have unique request ID and hundreds of other things, the only thing that you will accomplish is create inconvenience for an attacker.

Comment: The problem only appears when I'm logged in, otherwise it is impossible. I want to know how i can block this access in navigator dev tools